# Что делать с config.json после конфигурации bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap, sass

Я работаю над адаптивной веб-страницей, использую **bootstrap** и **SASS** (работаю на macOS, компилирую SASS через **Scout**).

Мне нужно было изменить некоторые параметры **bootstrap** по-умолчанию (такие как ширина контейнера и адаптивной сетки, разрешение экрана), я внес изменения с помощью http://getbootstrap.com/customize и скачал скомпилированную измененную версию **bootstrap**.

Теперь в папке **bootstrap**, помимо папок **CSS**, **fonts**, **JS** лежит файл **config.json**. Вопрос: должен ли я подключить его в **Scout** (в поле Config File), или положить в папку с веб-страницей (или просто проигнорировать)?